# How to use VS Code key binding for multiple action?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to trigger suggestions in vs code by pressing the `left` or `right` key.

{
"key": "left",
"command": "editor.action.triggerSuggest",
"when": "editorTextFocus"
},

It triggers the suggestions but the default behavior of these keys is not working. How to implement such a feature with its native functionality.

Comment: for this there is the key binding `Ctrl+Space`

Comment: @rioV8 thank you. I have used that shortcut for another use.

Comment: How exactly do you expect this to work? When would you expect the arrow keys to trigger suggestions and when - their usual cursor moving functions?

Comment: @KamenMinkov both at the same time

Comment: @KamenMinkov most likely `"when": "I_think_suggestions"` using the new VSC Theta Wave Brain Interface